# Convert results from url lib.request

Tags: python

I try to read data from the api geonames. I am using Python 3.7
This is working as it should.
Now I need to convert the results, but I don't know how.
This is my  code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

#Lat & lon of Hellevoetsluis-NL
lat=51.8
lon=4.131

var = '&lat=' + str(lat)+'&lng='+str(lon)+'&username=demo'
raw = urllib.request.urlopen(url2+var, timeout=4).read(10000)
raw = urllib.request.urlopen(url2+var, timeout=4).read(1000)

this is the result

b'{"geonames": [{\n  "adminCode1": "11",\n  "lng": "4.13333",\n  "distance": "3.7119",\n  "geonameId": 2754454,\n  "toponymName": "Hellevoetsluis",\n  "countryId": "2750405",\n  "fcl": "P",\n  "population": 21927,\n  "countryCode": "NL",\n  "name": "Hellevoetsluis",\n  "fclName": "city, village,...",\n  "countryName": "Netherlands",\n  "fcodeName": "populated place",\n  "adminName1": "South Holland",\n  "lat": "51.83333",\n  "fcode": "PPL"\n}]}'
```

And this is what I need:

```
{u'geonames': [{u'distance': u'0.19394', u'countryId': u'2750405', u'name': u'Hellevoetsluis', u'countryCode': u'NL', u'geonameId': 2754454, u'toponymName':
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What version of Python are you using? And no, 3.7 is not a valid version. It can't be 2.7, as you are using urllib.request, so it must be a 3.x release.

Comment: Why are you opening the URL and reading from it twice?

Comment: You are trying to load *JSON*. I've duplicated you to a post that shows you how to load that (second answer is for Python 3.x).

Comment: I using version 3.5.1, and in real I use only the last read of the url lib.request.urlopen!

Comment: Ho to read this post? This forum is new for me

Comment: Reload this page, the link is at the top in the yellow banner.